# Can't see files when browsing nginx webserver. Incorrect permissions?

Tags: nginx, permissions, yum, chmod, chown

I am using centos 7 with nginx 1.12 to host a yum repository locally.
When I try to browser the files via the browser, I can see the folders, but no files inside them. Im wondering if i might not have set the correct permissions or ownership.

**This is my setup:** 
I have synced all the packages for extras, updates etc into the path

`/var/www/html/repos/centos/7/os/x86_64`

The permissions look like this:

```
ls -l /var/www
drwxrwx--x. 3 root nginx 19 Aug 30 09:12 html

ls -l /var/www/html
drwxr-xr-x. 4 root nginx 32 Aug 30 09:12 repos

ls -l /var/www/html/repos
drwxr-xr-x. 3 root nginx 15 Aug 30 09:12 centos

ls -l /var/www/html/repos/centos
drwxr-xr-x. 3 root nginx 45 Aug 30 09:12 7

ls -l /var/www/html/repos/centos/7
drwxr-xr-x. 3 root nginx 20 Aug 30 09:12 os
drwxr-xr-x. 3 root nginx 20 Aug 30 09:12 updates
drwxr-xr-x. 3 root nginx 20 Aug 30 09:12 extras

ls -l /var/www/html/repos/centos/7/os
drwxr-xr-x. 8 alexl alexl 237 Aug 30 09:12 x86_64
```

I'm trying to access the packages folder via the browser and don't see any files. The permissions are:

```
ls -l /var/www/html/repos/centos/7/os/x86_64 | grep Packages
drwxr-x-r-x. 2 alexl alexl 565248 Aug 1 18:02 Packages
```

Permissions from a file inside the folder:

```
ls -l /var/www/html/repos/centos/7/os/x86_64/Packages | tail -1
-rw-r--r--. 1 alexl alexl 35380 Jul 4 2014 zziplib-utils-0.13.62-5.el7.x86_64.rpm
```

This is my nginx.conf file

```
user              nginx;  
worker_processes  auto;
error_log         /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid               /run/nginx.pid;

events {
  worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    log_format   main '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local]  $status '
    '"$request" $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
    '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log          /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile            on;
    tcp_nopush          on;
    tcp_nodelay         on;
    keepalive_timeout   65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;

    include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type        application/octet-stream;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

}
```

This is the configuration for the site:

```
server { # simple load balancing
  listen          80;
  server_name     mysecretdomain.com;
  root            /var/www/html/repos;

  location / {
    autoindex on;
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you get an error message or only an empty folder? Although it's a bit weird that you change ownership in some subfolder, either the nginx group or the "other" group always has read and execute permissions on the folders and files. So I would say the permissions are okay.

Comment: Check you log file for errors, also consider the SELinux security contexts and AVC denials (or simple run `restorecon -R /var/www/html/repos`)

Comment: I didn’t receive any errors in the logs, I’m getting 200 for hits to the folders. I’ll check the Selinux when I’m back at the computer. Thanks.

Comment: @HBruijn since your solution solved the problem, if you want to write it as an answer to the question I'll mark it as the correct solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to regular file-system permissions RHEL and CentOS have SELinux mandatory access controls enabled by default. Most likely your files are not labelled correctly.

Since you're using the default file-system location for web content, you can restore the  default SELinux security contexts with [`restorecon`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/restorecon)

```
 restorecon -R /var/www/html/repos
```

Moire detailed info about troubleshooting SELinux problems:  https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/selinux_users_and_administrators_guide/chap-security-enhanced_linux-troubleshooting